# dark brown patches on my tomato leaves

Tags: leaf-vegetables

What is causing dark brown patches on my tomato leaves [image]

[image]

Comment: In all such cases, round up the usual suspects. Any insect or fungus? Check with a magnifying glass and check both the plant affected and the nearby plants. Any unusual weather? Hot or cold, wet or dry. Is the fertilizer level correct? Any whacky chemicals nearby? Herbicide, road salt, paint, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I will do more inspection.